# Groovy String to CSV

Tags: groovy

I have a string input of the structure like:

```
[{name=John, dob=1970-07-27 00:00:00.0, score=81}, 
{name=Jane, dob=1970-07-28 00:00:00.0, score=77}]
```

I am trying to convert it to a CSV output. So expected output:

```
"name", "dob", "score"
"John", "1970-07-27 00:00:00.0", 81
"Jane", "1970-07-28 00:00:00.0", 77
```

So far I have tried something like

```
def js = "[{name=John, dob=1970-07-27 00:00:00.0, score=81}, {name=Jane, dob=1970-07-28 00:00:00.0, score=77}]"

def js = new JsonSlurper().parseText(s)

def columns = js*.keySet().flatten().unique()

def encode = { e -> e == null ? '' : e instanceof String ? /"$e"/ : "$e" }

// Print all the column names
println columns.collect { c -> encode( c ) }.join( ',' )

// Then create all the rows
println data.infile.collect { row ->
    // A row at a time
    columns.collect { colName -> encode( row[ colName ] ) }.join( ',' )
}.join( '\n' )
```

This fails with `groovy.json.JsonException: expecting '}' or ',' but got current char 'n'`
Defining var js without quotes fails with `expecting '}', found ','`

Thanks in advance

Comment: `js` isn't a legitimate String literal--or a legitimate List or Map literal, for that matter.

Comment: you are right. it would have been trivial to resolve if it was a legitimate list<map>. unfortunately this is what i have. and trying to stringify it with double quotes doesn't help either.

Comment: You can not type in JSON into a groovy source file and expect it to be parsed fine.  Either use it as a String, if that is what you have and use the JsonSlurper to parse it or write it with groovy list/map literals.

Comment: how and where from do you get this data? `[{name=John, dob=1970-07-27 00:00:00.0, score=81},...`

Comment: i created a simplified version of real data. the real data has 131 fields and is a dump we recieved from a government agency. don't have the option to go back and get a well formed json or legitimate list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this simple parser which will go splitting lines. If your input changes (i.e., comma or `=` is used in any other place), you will need a more complex parser:

```
input = '''[{name=John, dob=1970-07-27 00:00:00.0, score=81}, 
{name=Jane, dob=1970-07-28 00:00:00.0, score=77}, 
{name=Test, dob=1980-01-01 00:00:00.0, score=90}]'''


maps = (input =~ /\{(.*)\}/)
    .collect { 
        it[1]
            .split(', ')
            .collectEntries { entry ->
                entry.split '=' with {
                    [it.first(), it.last()]
                }
            }
    }


assert maps == [
    [name:'John', dob:'1970-07-27 00:00:00.0', score:'81'],
    [name:'Jane', dob:'1970-07-28 00:00:00.0', score:'77'], 
    [name:'Test', dob:'1980-01-01 00:00:00.0', score:'90']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code snippet**

```
    import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

    def s = '[{"name":"John", "dob":"1970-07-27 00:00:00.0", "score":81},{"name":"Jane", "dob":"1970-07-28 00:00:00.0", "score":77}]'
    def js = new JsonSlurper().parseText(s)
    def columns = js*.keySet().flatten().unique()
    def encode = { e -> e == null ? '' : e instanceof String ? /"$e"/ : "$e" }
    println columns.collect { c -> encode(c) }.join(',')

    js.each {
        println it.values().join(",")
    } ​
```

I used Groovy JsonSlurper to convert String to Map, For this you need to give proper json String.

Comment: unfortunately the string is not a well formed json

Comment: Then you have to format your raw String to proper Json String.You can use above parser for that.